# Как сделать картинки в одинаковой высоты и ширины блоки

Tags: css

Как это сделать? Разные размеры картинок?а блоки одинаковые и получается у меня разная высота, а должна быть одинаковая, и чтобы картинки подстраивались???

И без flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместить их в фон и задать `background-size: cover`:

```css
div {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div style=background-image:url(//gyazo.com/245b89755c8acd4463003dea4d61715b.png)></div>
<div style=background-image:url(//gyazo.com/5fd8cfef168b5fb3aa72b1a9f97943d6.png)></div>
```

Comment: а если  к примеру img имеет совсем не привычный aspect-ratio ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, и что? Просили-то квадрат - подрежется.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, это должно решить проблему

*Блокам:*

```
max-width: 150px;
max-height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Вместо 150px укажите свои размеры блоков

*Картинкам:*

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь вы это имели введу вам нужно к классу картинки добавить width:100%; height:100%;

```css
div
{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
float:left;
background: #000;
}
div img
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mCFZa1FwKlslDgth0hTsv3Km-rZ7yx2W7gdDkOG=s96" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mCFZa1FwKlslDgth0hTsv3Km-rZ7yx2W7gdDkOG=s96" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mCFZa1FwKlslDgth0hTsv3Km-rZ7yx2W7gdDkOG=s96" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо так...

```html
<style>
.bubu {width: 180px; height: 180px; margin: 5px; border: 3px solid orange;}
</style>

<img class="bubu" src="https://gyazo.com/245b89755c8acd4463003dea4d61715b.png">
<img class="bubu" src="https://gyazo.com/5fd8cfef168b5fb3aa72b1a9f97943d6.png">
```

Не обязательно их ставить внутри блоков... если должен быть такой простой ряд картинок. Если без блоков никак, это дело можно организовать так:

```html
<style>
.bubu {width: 180px; height: 180px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; border: 3px solid orange;}
.bubu img {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
</style>

<div class="bubu"><img src="https://gyazo.com/245b89755c8acd4463003dea4d61715b.png"></div>
<div class="bubu"><img src="https://gyazo.com/5fd8cfef168b5fb3aa72b1a9f97943d6.png"></div>
```

Вопрос, зачем добавлять лишний код, если на выходе должно получиться то же самое) У тегов img (и всех остальных одиночных) есть минус - у них нет псевдоэлементов `:before` и `:after`